# Using Picasso library with ImageSwitcher is causing Object out of Memory errors

Tags: android, picasso, imageswitcher

I want to load large bitmaps efficiently in my Image Switcher and i have been using Picasso for this purpose but now i am stuck at this point. Without Picasso a lot of `OOMs` and other nasty exceptions please tell me if I can use this library with Image Switcher too.
If yes then provide sample code.

Thanks!

```
imswitch.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

        @Override
        public View makeView() {
              ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
              imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
              imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
              return imageView;
        }
    } );
```

**And onClick:**

```
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               currentIndex++;
               // If index reaches maximum reset it
                if(currentIndex==messageCount)
                    currentIndex=0;
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imswitch);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageIds[currentIndex]).into(imageView);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pressed "+currentIndex,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: what is you're issue?

Comment: I have a bunch of large bitmaps and i want to show them on image switcher and was wondering if Picasso is of any help here.

Comment: does your image come from the internet? if it true, so you can use picasso for fetch those images,

Comment: No i have stored images in drawable directory and i want to show them in Image Switcher. I know how to set images on ImageView using Picasso but i am unaware of doing same for Image Switcher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possible way is to create own implementation using Target interface.

https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html

```
public class ImageSwitcherPicasso implements Target {

        private ImageSwitcher mImageSwitcher;
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageSwitcherPicasso(Context context, ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher){
            mImageSwitcher = imageSwitcher;
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            mImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {

        }

    }
```

Than just use as follow

```
    ImageSwitcherPicasso mImageSwitcherPicasso = new ImageSwitcherPicasso(getActivity(), playerBackground);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(path)).into(mImageSwitcherPicasso);
```

where playerBackground is reference to ImageSwitcher

Comment: thanks for reply ..anyways problem has been sorted out.